# SQL statement returning in wrong format

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a query to return a post id and a timestamp in one object. I have the post ID and the timestamp returning, but the timestamp key is post_id, and it should be timestamp. Also, it's storing it as a individual item in the array, and I want it to be combined with the post_id. Here's my sql statement:

```
$meta_key = '_birs_client_id';
    $meta_value = $client_id[0]->post_id; 
    $adjusted_time = strtotime("+1 day");
    $timestamp_meta_key = '_birs_appointment_timestamp';

    $sql = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_habitera_postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = %d
    UNION 
    SELECT meta_value FROM wp_habitera_postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s";
    $appointments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql, $meta_key, $meta_value, $timestamp_meta_key));
```

Here's an example subset of my return from the sql statement:

```
[19] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 996
    )

[20] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 999
    )

[21] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 1002
    )

[22] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 1398370500
    )

[23] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 1398284100
    )

[24] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 1398196800
    )
```

This is the format I'm trying to get:

```
[18] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 993
        [timestamp] => 1398370500
    )
```

Can someone tell me how to get it in this format?

EDIT

here's a picture of the database I'm working with that should help clarify:

http://i59.tinypic.com/10sgml3.png

the 2 rows I'm interested in are the timestamp and appointment id. The column before the timestamp column "1000" is the post id that matches up with the column after the post id column "1000" again.

Comment: How would you want that to be combined? How do you know thich `post_id` matches with which `timestamp`? As far as I can tell there is no relation between them, and not even any guarantee that you will have as many timestamps as post_ids.

Comment: the post_id does match up with the timestamp just in the wrong column. I edited the post with an image to help visualize the problem.

Comment: The picture helps, but it'd help more an sqlfiddle in http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT >** My last answer was rubbish, edited to try to give an answer to the question.

A UNION won't help you to solve the problem: all the values retrieved from the DDBB are concatenated, the first query will retrieve the values of the field `post`, and the second one the values of the `timestamp`, but with the UNION you're telling MySQL to put them together in the same field. What you'll need to do is `JOIN` the table with itself to get the values you want as different fields, but for that you need to establish the a relationship between the rows. I can't say what is that relationship without knowing the structure of your table and the data it has, but if you write that relation rule in the query below you'll have the query you want:

```
SELECT post_id, meta_value as timestamp 
FROM wp_habitera_postmeta wphp1
INNER JOIN wp_habitera_postmeta wphp2
ON ( RELATION_RULE_BETWEEN_ROWS_ON_YOUR_TABLE )
WHERE meta_value = %d
```

Comment: SELECT post_id FROM wp_habitera_postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = %d - this is the post_id

    SELECT meta_value FROM wp_habitera_postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s - this is the timestamp.

Comment: Join was the solution, with a little fudging of this I got it to work. Thank you